# Search through file and only returning the first x results in Python

Tags: python

Alright, so I'm trying to code a bot for Discord that searches through a defined file for a defined string, right now it's working but it's returning every instance of the string, so like if someone was to look for  in file "b" it would literally print every single line containing that letter until the end, which in the bots case, causes a denial of service due to overuse of memory and CPU.

What I want it to do is only return the first like 10 or 20 results from the file, then stop searching. It's coded for discord.py

Here's the code:

````
@client.command()
async def search(arg1, arg2):
    await client.say("Searching for "+arg1+" in "+arg2+"...")
    with open("DIRECTORY/"+arg2, 'r') as inF:
        for line in inF:
            if arg1 in line:
                await client.say("```"+line+"```")
````

What do I need to change or add?

Comment: `break` is what you are looking for

Comment: How would I implement it, I honestly don't have much knowledge in coding. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe add a counter to keep track of how many you have already found and if you have found more than 20, stop. For example:

````
    with open("DIRECTORY/"+arg2, 'r') as inF:
    numFound = 0
    for line in inF:

        if arg1 in line:

            await client.say("```"+line+"```")
            numFound += 1
            if numFound == 20:
                break
````

Comment: Alright, I'll try it out right now and come back if it works out for me.